# Add DeepDiff output back to original df

Tags: python, pandas, deep-diff

I apologize if this is a possible duplicate and a trivial question. I am trying to calculate the difference between `diff` column in my df for consecutive rows.

Here is my code for the same:

```
z = prac_df.sort_values(['customer_id', 'delivery_date'])

grouped = z.groupby('customer_id')
differences = []
for name, group in grouped:
    group = group.sort_values('delivery_date')
    for i in range(1, len(group)):
        diff = DeepDiff(group.iloc[i-1]['diff'], group.iloc[i]['diff'])
        if diff:
            differences.append(diff)
        else:
            differences.append('no change')
```

How can I add the `differences` back to my original df `z`?

Comment: I tried that and get this: `ValueError: Length of values (8662) does not match length of index (9301)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my mistaken comment, Anyway you can do the following:

```
z['diff'] = 0
for name, group in grouped:
    d = ['first item']
    group = group.sort_values('delivery_date')
    for i in range(1, len(group)):
        diff = DeepDiff(group.iloc[i-1]['diff'], group.iloc[i]['diff']) 
        if diff:
            d.append(diff)
        else:
            d.append('no change')
    z.loc[group.index, 'diff'] = d
```

Note that you need a default value for first items

Comment: default value means?

Comment: We will not calculate the difference between first item of each group with another item, thus we need to set it to a value